# hover animation slides under mouse causing hover animation to run again

Tags: jquery, animation, raphael

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jAThU/2/

```
var paper = Raphael("paper", 500, 500);

var rect1 = paper.rect(0,0, 200, 200).attr({'fill':'#b90e0a'});
var rect2 = paper.rect(200,0, 200, 200).attr({'fill':'#86171d'});

var box1 = paper.rect(200,0, 100, 100).attr(
               {'fill':'#ffffff','stroke':'#000000','opacity':0}
           );
box1.toBack();
var box2 = paper.rect(400,0, 100, 100).attr(
               {'fill':'#ffffff','stroke':'#000000','opacity':0}
           );
box2.toBack();

var set1 = paper.set(rect1,box1);
var set2 = paper.set(rect2,box2);

set1.hoverset(paper, function() {
    box1.toFront();
    box1.stop().animate(
        {'opacity':'1','transform':'t-50,0'},
        250, 
        "cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86)"
    );
}, function() {
    box1.stop().animate(
        {'opacity':'0','transform':'t50,0'}, 
        250, 
        "cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86)", 
         function() { box1.toBack(); }
    );
});

set2.hoverset(paper, function() {
    box2.toFront();
    box2.stop().animate(
        {'opacity':'1','transform':'t-50,0'}, 
        250, 
        "cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86)"
    );
}, function() {
    box2.stop().animate(
        {'opacity':'0','transform':'t50,0'}, 
        250, 
        "cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86)", 
        function() { box2.toBack(); }
    );
});
```

Hovering over the red or maroon boxes will cause a smaller white box to slide in.

**Problem:** If you hover over the white box, then move your mouse to the right just outside the white box, you will see the animation slides the box under the mouse triggering the hover function again. This causes an undesirable flickering effect.

**Edit:** I still need the pointer events on the white box because it will have some clickable info on it.

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. I've tried adding a box over the animation, but then the hover won't take effect on the box below. I've tried adding a delay, but there is still a flickering effect. I've tried unbinding the hover function.

**Question:** How do I eliminate this flickering effect? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable pointer events on the white box, so

```
.box {
    pointer-events: none;
}

box1.node.setAttribute("class", "box");
box2.node.setAttribute("class", "box");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jAThU/4/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ian. However, I need to have mouse events on the white box because it will have some clickable info on it. I have edited my question above. I'm thinking this is headed in the right direction, though. Maybe there is a way I can disable events while the animation running and then enable them when the animation is compete. ?